# React : test a function which is passed as a props and is triggered by the parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sinon, jestjs

I'm trying to trigger a click event for my test. As this :

```
describe('Button', function() {
      test('is clicked when player two is pending', (props ={}) => {
        const mockRandomAdv = sinon.spy();

         const tree = shallow(
            <FightButton  
                        button="Random adversary"
                        isPlayerTwoPending={true}
                        isPlayerOnePending={false}
                        onClick={mockRandomAdv}

             />
        );

       tree.find('Button').simulate('click');
       //expect(mockRandomAdv.calledOnce).toEqual(true);

        console.log(tree.props().children.onClick)
        //.not.toBe('fight-button random');
    });
});
```

The first expectation return false so the click is not triggered.
When i console.log() the click event it returns undefined.
Here is my child (which is not the last last child).

```
<Button
        onClick={ () => { this.props.randomAdversary }}
        class="fight-button random"
        button="Random adversary"
 />
```

And here is the parent that is calling the child and who describe the method :

```
class Board extends Component {

constructor(props) {
..my constructor
}

randomAdversary() { 
...my function 
}
    return (<div> <FightButton
                            isPlayerTwoPending={this.state.adversaryPending}
                            isPlayerOnePending={this.state.characterPending}
                            isPlayerOneTheWinner={this.state.heroWin}
                            isFighting={this.state.fighting}
                            randomAdversary={this.randomAdversary}
                            fight={this.fight(100)}
                            playAgain={this.playAgain()}
                          />
            </div>
    )
}
```

When i click, the class of my button must change. But the same when i console.log the class, it has no changed. Is something wrong with my test ?

Comment: Try to pass `randomAdversary={mockRandomAdv}` in `shallow(<FightButton.../>);`

Comment: And `onClick={ () => { this.props.randomAdversary }}` should be `onClick={ () => { this.props.randomAdversary() }}`

Comment: Okay, seems that the fix was easy, the bind event is triggered now. But now i have to refractor my code to be more readable like binding states on my child and not only on the parent to make it testable, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the button, I don't see calling the function correctly. I'ts actually doing nothing, you need to execute the function like this:

```
<Button
    onClick={ () => { this.props.randomAdversary() }} // Add the `()`
    class="fight-button random"
    button="Random adversary"
/>
```

Comment: yes, as noticed in the comment that solutions seems to make the call triggered, thanks.